# Why is this PHP error script not emailing me for fatal errors?

Tags: php

I am using the following script from nettuts:

```
// Our custom error handler  
function error_engine($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars)  

{  
    $email = " 
        <p>An error ($number) occurred on line  
        <strong>$line</strong> and in the <strong>file: $file.</strong>  
        <p> $message </p>";  

    $email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars, 1) . "</pre>";  

    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

    // Email the error to someone...  
    error_log($email, 1, 'example@example.com', $headers);  


    if ( ($number !== E_NOTICE) && ($number < 2048) ) {  
        die("There was an error. Please try again later.");  
    }  
}  

// We should use our custom function to handle errors.  
set_error_handler('error_engine');
```

It works fine for notices and warnings and such, but when I purposely break my script, say by changing "mysqli_connect" to "mysqy_connct" I get the fatal error printing out on the screen and no email!

Is an error like that beyond the scope of this type of error logging/reporting?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's listed in the [documentation](http://en.php.net/set_error_handler):

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.

Answer (score 3):

`set_error_handler/set_exception_handler` does not handle all possible errors. Namely, parse errors aren't caught by it. I can't tell you exactly what it doesn't handle. A general rule is that the these handlers are invoked when something that would have been caught by a `try catch` or when `trigger_error` is called

To trap errors that aren't caught by `set_error_handler/set_exception_handler` Many frameworks use a combination of [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)